# how distinct and different results of the same field, differentiating rows

Tags: mysql

I have a table with only an id field, I would get the result of this field, as distintic id and another column all have different IDs and can not be equal and also results already found previously...EX:

**Id_field**

1

2

3

**I want the following result:**

1 - 2

1 - 3

2 - 3

**I d'nt**

1 - 1

2 - 2

3 - 3

**and result previously stated**

2 - 1

3 - 1

3 - 2

Comment: Please, post your current query

Comment: What is the criteria for that result

Comment: Huh? You have a column with one ID and you want to select all pairs of IDs of which the first one is strictly less than the other one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple self join?

```
SELECT a.id_field, b.id_field
FROM SomeTable a
INNER JOIN SomeTable b
ON a.id_field < b.id_field
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t2.id AS id2,t1.id AS id1
FROM t AS t1
JOIN t AS t2 ON (t1.id > t2.id);
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd4bf/7)